# looking for emacs templates for javascript

Tags: javascript, emacs

does anyone know a emacs template for javascript?

in particular, am looking for template for either yasnippet or autocomplete.

one minute google or emacswiki search didn't find anything.

(am already using both js2-mode and js-mode (epresso), they don't appear to have name completion or template builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few around, but not very comprehensive...

Try these...

- http://github.com/azer/js-yasnippets

Azer's looking for people to fork and expand the list.

Comment: good answer. Though that site has only like 10 templates, while js has like few hundreds functions, methods, etc. Am going to work one out i think.

Comment: I was as surprised as you are.